# How to pause circular progress bar in android studio Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar

I am done starting circular progress bar but not able to pause.

`binding.start.setOnClickListener { binding.circularProgressBar.apply { progress=0f setProgressWithAnimationk(60f,60000) progressMax=60f}`

waiting your solutions
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try `binding.circularProgressBar.indeterminateMode = true`

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.